# Communication between two fragment in two activity

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have two Activity A and B, in A I have fragment A1 and in B I have fragment B1
When I click button in A I intent to activity B. Now I want when click  button in fragment B1 on B I will call method in fragment A1. How I can do it?( use onActivityResult or broadcast intent or other? When I use onActivityResult activity A refresh all data and I don't want it.)
[Closed]

Comment: You cannot call a method on a fragment that is not displayed.

Comment: What do you mean by "refresh all data"?

Comment: Thank every one I did it

Answer (score 1):

You cannot call a method on a fragment that is not displayed. To solve this problem, you must think of it as communicating between activities more than communicating between fragments. You should start activity B with `startActivityForResult()`. Then when the user clicks the button in fragment B1, set the result and `finish()` the activity. Now, in activity A, send the data to fragment A1 when the result is received.

The above is a general outline for solving your problem. You should research the details for correctly using `startActivityForResult()` to flag this out.

Comment: thank you, I used shared preference save my value in fragment B1 and check in onResume in fragment A1 and if it change I will call method and it run very good.

Comment: @HoaTranVan glad you found a solution